# Why is my Visual Studio Code getting server error messages when trying to debug

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, debugging

Why am I getting an IIS error when I try to debug a javascript source file in Visual Studio Code?  Here is my launch.json file

```
 // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"            
    },
    {
        "type": "firefox",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch firefox against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```

And the error message from IIS is: Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:"

Answer (score 1):

in the folder that contains your project file there will be a .vscode file, just delete it and you will be good to go.

Comment: why does this fix the problem? that's a configuration directory. you're telling the user to just nuke all their workspace configuration? how is that a good solution?

Comment: Hi starball, what's your solution?