Why Won't the VSCode Debugger Attach To (Any Browser) When I hit the Play button?
I need some unusual help.  My VSCode debug capability is broken, and I don't know how to fix it.
Whenever I click the "play" button in VSCode the project builds, runs, and launches Chrome/Edge/Firefox/Brave ... but when the browser launches it flips me the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED bird.
The debug window in VSCode tells me:

Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:"

(and yes, it's the same chrome-error for Edge)
and ChatGPT/Copilot haven't been much help either:

I've dumped the node_modules folder and npm cache clean --force'd it.
I've checked AND unchecked these in DevTools, in all combinations:

CSS Source Maps,
JavaScript Source Maps and
Allow DevTools To load resources […] from remote file paths.


I added "sourceMap": true, to the tsconfig.json file, and done the equivalent in the .env file.
I R[a]n as Administrator
I reinstalled VSCode
I deleted and recreated the .vscode directory (and the launch.json within).
I tried adding a launch configuration to launch.json, and the 'npm start' configuration works to launch the site, but it doesn't hit any breakpoints while it's running.

EDIT 1: I have also analyzed my launch.json:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
    }, 
  ]
}

The url and port are correct in url, and I have tried both "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src" (for the src folder) and "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}" (for just the workspace) - no other values really make sense to me.
EDIT 2 I've also gone to More tools → Dev Tools → Settings Gear → Workspace and added my ${workspace} and ${workspace}/src folders to Chrome without success.

You need to check the "launch.json" file. The debugging URL is set there. Make sure that it's correct. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

@VladDX  Yep, I tried that - no joy.  See my Edit 1.

related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77859610/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77809447/11107541

@ScottBaker - yes the previous SOs had advised appropriate. First launch in a different terminal by either npm start or npm run dev and Play afterwards.
